# hadoop "ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server" error

Tags: hadoop

There are a lot of ideas on how to resolve this hadoop error

```
15/04/17 10:59:57 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 0 time(s).
```

However, I tried all and still see that error! Here are my configurations

1) core-site.xml

```
$ cat ../../apache/hadoop-1.0.2/conf/core-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

2) mapred-site.xml

```
$ cat ../../apache/hadoop-1.0.2/conf/mapred-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx512m</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

3) iptables for the port

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables
*filter
:INP UT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5901 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2049 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 54310 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 54311 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT

# /etc/init.d/iptables restart
iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter          [  OK  ]
iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]
iptables: Applying firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]

$ netstat -an | grep 54310
$ netstat -an | grep 54311
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:54311     :::*                        LISTEN
tcp      238      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:54311      ::ffff:127.0.0.1:44216      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:44216      ::ffff:127.0.0.1:54311      ESTABLISHED
```

4) starting hadoop

```
$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-all.sh
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

starting namenode, logging to /home/mahmood/bigdatabench/apache/hadoop-1.0.2/libexec/../logs/hadoop-mahmood-namenode-tiger.out
mahmood@localhost's password:
localhost: Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
localhost:
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/mahmood/bigdatabench/apache/hadoop-1.0.2/libexec/../logs/hadoop-mahmood-datanode-tiger.out
mahmood@localhost's password:
localhost: Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
localhost:
localhost: secondarynamenode running as process 7583. Stop it first.
jobtracker running as process 7792. Stop it first.
mahmood@localhost's password:
localhost: Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
localhost:
localhost: tasktracker running as process 8019. Stop it first.
```

5) check java processes

```
$ jps
10292 Jps
8019 TaskTracker
7792 JobTracker
7583 SecondaryNameNode
```

6) Still I get that error

```
$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:54310/
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

15/04/17 10:59:57 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 0 time(s).
15/04/17 10:59:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 1 time(s).
15/04/17 10:59:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 2 time(s).
15/04/17 11:00:00 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 3 time(s).
15/04/17 11:00:01 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 4 time(s).
15/04/17 11:00:02 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 5 time(s).
15/04/17 11:00:03 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 6 time(s).
15/04/17 11:00:04 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 7 time(s).
15/04/17 11:00:05 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 8 time(s).
15/04/17 11:00:06 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 9 time(s).
Bad connection to FS. command aborted. exception: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

UPDATE:

While I thought that I had formatted the filesystem, it turns out that the hdfs format command aborted and I didn't noticed. The reason for that was I answered this question `Re-format filesystem in /home/mahmood/bigdatabench/apache/hadoop-1.0.2/folders/name ? (Y or N)` with **y**. However the correct answer is to press **Y** (capital letter!!).

So the correct steps are

1- stop-all.sh

2- hadoop namenode -format

3- start-all.sh

The ipc error has been gone :)

How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you show your '/etc/hosts' file from your namenode server?

Comment: @IsraelVarea I am also facing the same issue and I am a complete newbie, how to get this file?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are running this command from a client machine , in your config files you need to give ip address/hostname instead of localhost to avoid this type of problems. Try to have hostnames in your config files and try once again.

Comment: I have replaced `localhost:54310` with `192.168.1.5:54310` (the same with 54311). Stop and start hadoop again but still get the same error.

Comment: Question: Why it is asking for password when start (and stop) hadoop? I mean start-all.sh and stop-all.sh

Comment: you need to setup password less ssh for your localhost. I mean ssh locahost should be password less. Use this ... http://hortonworks.com/kb/generating-ssh-keys-for-passwordless-login/

Comment: is your namenode active ?

Comment: how to check activity of namenode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75475/discussion-between-mahmood-and-venkata-karthik).

Answer (score 0):

This error is been handled now.

Please check below list of configurations which should be performed at master and datanodes.

Master:
1) Disable IP v6
2) Disable the firewall
3) Use Physical IP in hdfs-site.xml and mapered XML file instead of localhost.
4) In etc/hosts file, please comment all entries except master physical IP and datanode physical IP address. All IP starting from 127.*** and IP v6 entries should be commented.

Datanode:
1) In etc/hosts file, please comment all entries except master physical IP and datanode physical IP address. All IP starting from 127.*** and IP v6 entries should be commented.
2) Use Physical IP in hdfs-site.xml and mapered XML file instead of localhost.